# Error with chef recipes when running vagrant up

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, vagrant, chef-infra

Trying to run vagrant up for a rails project and it throughs a very generic error after mysql installation. Mysql is installed correctly but when I try to run the server it exits unexpectedly.

Vagrant up error:

```
==> default: Thank you for installing Chef!
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
==> default: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:21:14-04:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:21:17-04:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.8.0 ***
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:21:17-04:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 7277
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:21:18-04:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[mama::dev]"] from JSON
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:21:18-04:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[mama::dev]]
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:21:18-04:00] INFO: Run List expands to [mama::dev]
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:21:18-04:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for localhost.localdomain
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:21:18-04:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:21:18-04:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:21:33-04:00] INFO: package[default :create mysql55-mysql-server] installing mysql55-mysql-server-5.5.40-2.el5 from updates repository
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: file[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/my.cnf] backed up to /var/chef/backup/opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/my.cnf.chef-20150310132352.522349
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: file[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/my.cnf] deleted file at /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/my.cnf
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: link[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/share/my-default.cnf] created
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default] created directory /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default] owner changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default] group changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default] mode changed to 750
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/conf.d] created directory /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/conf.d
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/conf.d] owner changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/conf.d] group changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/conf.d] mode changed to 750
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/var/run/mysql-default] created directory /opt/rh/mysql55/root/var/run/mysql-default
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/var/run/mysql-default] owner changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/var/run/mysql-default] group changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/var/run/mysql-default] mode changed to 755
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/var/log/mysql-default] created directory /opt/rh/mysql55/root/var/log/mysql-default
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/var/log/mysql-default] owner changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/var/log/mysql-default] group changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:52-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/var/log/mysql-default] mode changed to 750
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:53-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /var/lib/mysql-default] created directory /var/lib/mysql-default
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:53-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /var/lib/mysql-default] owner changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:53-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /var/lib/mysql-default] group changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:53-04:00] INFO: directory[default :create /var/lib/mysql-default] mode changed to 750
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:53-04:00] INFO: template[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/my.cnf] created file /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/my.cnf
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:53-04:00] INFO: template[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/my.cnf] updated file contents /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/my.cnf
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:53-04:00] INFO: template[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/my.cnf] owner changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:53-04:00] INFO: template[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/my.cnf] group changed to 27
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:53-04:00] INFO: template[default :create /opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/mysql-default/my.cnf] mode changed to 600
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:53-04:00] INFO: bash[default :create initialize mysql database] ran successfully
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:53-04:00] INFO: bash[default :create initialize mysql database] sending run action to bash[default :create initial records] (delayed)
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:57-04:00] INFO: bash[default :create initial records] ran successfully
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:57-04:00] INFO: template[default :start /etc/init.d/mysql-default] created file /etc/init.d/mysql-default
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:57-04:00] INFO: template[default :start /etc/init.d/mysql-default] updated file contents /etc/init.d/mysql-default
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:57-04:00] INFO: template[default :start /etc/init.d/mysql-default] owner changed to 0
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:57-04:00] INFO: template[default :start /etc/init.d/mysql-default] group changed to 0
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:57-04:00] INFO: template[default :start /etc/init.d/mysql-default] mode changed to 755
==> default: [2015-03-10T13:23:58-04:00] INFO: service[default :start mysql-default] enabled
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't see any error. And no code to debug, impossible to tell what your issue is

Comment: Did you cut out part of that log?  It doesn't show any errors which is unlikely if that's the full output.

Comment: @user3783834, Do you can put full log? You can find in /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out

Comment: There is not anything there. I did not cut anything of the log.

Comment: Can you add `-l debug` to your run?

Comment: having same issue, its a complete log, there is no error message displaying! as you can see the full log